# Position in a link of a turtle

Tags: time, position, netlogo, move

**Is there an option in NetLogo to know in which link is located a citizen that is moving in a network or links at every tick?**

I am not asking for the code or anyone solution for me. I want only a tip as I already check in the NetLogo dictionary the options available relate to turtles and links but I cannot find the way.

Comment: A citizen may move from the position of turtleA to the position of turtleB with turtleA and turtleB connected by a link, but the moving citizen is not aware of the link. In the code at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49646823/move-agents-in-nodes, they simply jump from one end of the link to the other. But you can also have them `face` the other end and move `forward`, as in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49565308/copy-the-link-breed-variable-in-the-patch-below. In that case, you can ask them for the `patch` they are on.

Comment: Can you make the question more precise and specific? "in which link is located" doesn't have a single clear meaning.